# Error with dplyr but not plyr with ezANOVA on grouped data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have an existing workflow where I apply an analysis of variance (ANOVA) using `ez::ezANOVA` to each section of a data frame split by a factor. I'd like to update my old version of this using `ddply` in `plyr` to a new version using `dplyr`. Here's a toy example that works with `ddply`:

```
require(dplyr)
require(plyr)
require(ez)

X = data.frame(
  x1 = rep(factor(letters[1:2]), 20),
  x2 = rep(factor(letters[1:2]), 10, each = 2),
  id = factor(sort(rep(1:10, 4)))
)

# stack individual data frames into one large data frame
df = X[rep(seq_len(nrow(X)), 10),]

# add an index column to track group
df$grp = sort(rep(1:10, nrow(X)))

# add an arbitrary outcome variable
df$y = runif(400)

# define a function that extracts p-values from ezANOVA output
PVals = function(df) {
  ezANOVA(
    data = df, dv = y, wid = id, 
    within = .(x1, x2))[[1]][5]
}
```

I get what I want with ddply:

```
ddply(df, .(grp), PVals)
```

I'd like to use the dplyr approach:

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% do(PVals(.))
```

But this generates the error:

> Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,     :   "dv" must be numeric.

So my assumption is that `group_by` returns an object that does not contain the same class of variables as the original data frame? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I figured it out, a simple mistake. My function `PVals` needs a data frame. This works: `df %>% group_by(grp) %>% do(PVals(data.frame(.)))`